# How can I use the data returned from a sub-query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

I have a sub-query that just gets the sum of the number of items sold per itemID. I'd like to get the result of that sub-query and multiply it by the items price. But when I try to reference the column alias I used for the sub-query, Slq Server gives me an error saying the column I'm trying to use is invalid. Here's my sql...

```
SELECT     TOP (100) PERCENT Shop_1.ShopName, CustomerOrdersDtl_1.ItemID, ItemList_1.ItemName, SUM(CustomerOrdersDtl_1.Amount) AS tAmount
FROM         dbo.CustomerOrders AS CustomerOrders_1 INNER JOIN
                      dbo.CustomerOrdersDtl AS CustomerOrdersDtl_1 ON CustomerOrders_1.ID = CustomerOrdersDtl_1.CustomerOrdersID INNER JOIN
                      dbo.ItemList AS ItemList_1 ON CustomerOrdersDtl_1.ItemID = ItemList_1.ID INNER JOIN
                      dbo.Shop AS Shop_1 ON CustomerOrders_1.ShopID = Shop_1.ID
GROUP BY Shop_1.ShopName, CustomerOrdersDtl_1.ItemID, ItemList_1.ItemName, ItemList_1.Price
ORDER BY Shop_1.ShopName
```

The Column I'm trying to use is tAmount. I'd like to have another column after it, TotalCost, that shows the Price*tAmount. When I put (Itemlist_1.Price*tAmount) as TotalItemCost, I get an error saying tAmount is an invalid column.

Is it even possible to reference the data returned by a sub-query? Or is there another way to do this?

Thanks very much in advance for any and all help. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `tAmount` column isn't available within the query. Something like `SUM(CustomerOrdersDtl_1.Amount) * Itemlist_1.Price` might work.

Otherwise try using a sub-select:

```
SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT sqry.ShopName, sqry.ItemID, sqry.ItemName, sqry.tAmount, sqry.Price*sqry.tAmount as TotalItemCost
FROM
(SELECT     Shop_1.ShopName AS ShopName, CustomerOrdersDtl_1.ItemID AS ItemID, ItemList_1.ItemName AS ItemName, SUM(CustomerOrdersDtl_1.Amount) AS tAmount, Itemlist_1.Price AS Price
FROM         dbo.CustomerOrders AS CustomerOrders_1 INNER JOIN
                      dbo.CustomerOrdersDtl AS CustomerOrdersDtl_1 ON CustomerOrders_1.ID = CustomerOrdersDtl_1.CustomerOrdersID INNER JOIN
                      dbo.ItemList AS ItemList_1 ON CustomerOrdersDtl_1.ItemID = ItemList_1.ID INNER JOIN
                      dbo.Shop AS Shop_1 ON CustomerOrders_1.ShopID = Shop_1.ID
GROUP BY Shop_1.ShopName, CustomerOrdersDtl_1.ItemID, ItemList_1.ItemName, ItemList_1.Price) as sqry
ORDER BY sqry.ShopName
```

Comment: The `ORDER BY` item references `Shop_1` which is invalid in that context. It should be either `sqry.ShopName` (if you want to be specific) or simply `ShopName` (because the subquery is the only table being selected from).

Comment: Thank you. Your suggestion worked just the way I wanted it. Funny why I didn't think of that. Most times, the simple answers really are the best. Thanks again! :)

Comment: @jay santos: While you've confirmed that the answer has worked for you, it's a good practice to *accept* it formally too (tick the check mark next to the answer). That way the other visitors of this page would be able to locate the working solution right away.

Answer (score 2):

You can't reference the column alias tAmount within the scope of the same query. You have to spell out the calculation in full again as you have it. If you want to use the column name tAmount, you have to use sub-queries:

This example breaks:

```
select 1 * 2 as tAmount, tAmount
```

This example works:

```
select tbl.tAmount, tbl.tAmount * 2 from 
( select 1 * 2 as tAmount ) as tbl
```

Comment: Thank you for this bit of code. It actually answered another problem we were having. Thanks again. :)

Answer (score 0):

maybe try: SUM(Itemlist_1.Price*CustomerOrdersDtl_1.Amount) AS TotalItemCost?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I'll definitely use this in another report. For this particular one, I need the count of items sold per shop. Thanks you very much for the info. :)